# C# event handlers : when are the subscribers invoked?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling

After doing some reading here is what I think is happening, and I am just looking for confirmation or correction.

The samples below will be using anonymous lambdas for brevity, obviously doing that you would lose the ability to unsubscribe.

```
MyEvent += (sender, args) => {Console.WriteLine("One")};
MyEvent += (sender, args) => {Console.WriteLine("Two")};
MyEvent += (sender, args) => {Console.WriteLine("Three")};
```

With the subscribers in place, we would invoke the Event:

```
var handler = MyEvent;
if(handler != null){
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty) // <-- Interested in this moment
}
```

So here is where I will need correcting/clarification/guidance.  As I understand it, what invoking handler is effectively doing is (I understand it's not doing EXACTLY this, this is for illustrative purposes only).

```
foreach(var subscriber in self){
    subscriber(sender, args);
}
```

I'm explicitly not talking about using this with `BeginInvoke`. So what happens is basically invoking the handler causes the handler to loop through all of it's subscribers in some undefined order and invoke them passing the appropriate args from the invoking thread (in this example, again not talking about `BeginInvoke`)

Put another way, `handler(this, EventArgs.Empty)` is basically just doing this immediately, on the invoking thread:

```
anonymous1(..., ...)
anonymous2(..., ...)
anonymous3(..., ...)
```

Modifying the above slightly:

```
var handler = MyEvent;
if(handler != null){
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty) // <-- Interested in this moment
}

Console.WriteLine("Done Invoking Subscribers");
```

We can always expect the output to be (since none of our subscribers are async and we are not using BeginInvoke):

```
// some undefined order of the following 3 lines:

One
Two
Three

// Always followed by
Done Invoking Subscribers
```

Generally speaking, do I have this idea right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

Sorry to be that direct but the simple answer is yes, that's how it works.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, the simple answer! =) thanks! I have to wait an additional 5 min to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Sometimes the best answers are simple :)